# Populate Dropdown from filtered data in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I have a data set that contains a number of groups and each group has a number of individuals.

I have a tab in a report which shows some statistics for all the groups as a whole.

I have another tab which has a filter to only show info for selected groups in that tab.

I have a third tab, which I want to show info for individuals within whatever group is selected on the second tab.

I have 2 filters setup for these, a 'group' filter and an 'individual' filter so that I can easily add the filter to any visualizations.

I am trying to only show individuals within a group selected on the second tab ('group' filter) on the filter in the third tab ('individual' filter) however this will only happen when I set that filter to the 'group' filter'. This would be OK except when I go  back to tab 2 to change the group (and thus the available individuals on the third tab) I only have one group available in this filter IF I have selected an individual on the third tab.

Is there any way to do the following:

1. Only show individuals based on 'group' filter in the filter on the third tab, which will effect the 'individual' filter. All groups should be available in the groups filter independent of the individual selection on third tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not with using standard filters. The fact that you have these broken up across tabs doesn't change the fact. **When you apply a filter, you are filtering the underlying data-set as whole.** Thus, when you select an *individual selection* on the third tab, it is filtering the underlying data table which feeds all three tabs to this level.

What you can do, is add in an **Action Control** that will only refresh / remove the filters applied on a certain tab. This will be *similar* to clicking the **Reset All Filters** button on the tool bar, except we can apply this to your specific page.... in this case the *third tab*.

In a text area on the *second tab*

- `Right Click > Edit Text Area > Insert Action Control`
- Set the Display text to what ever you want
- Control type: Button or Image... perhaps [something like this](https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/gray-toolbar-4/512/rotate-512.png)
- Available actions > Pages and visualizations: Navigate to the *third tab* page name and click *Add*
- Available actions > Functions: Navigate to *Reset All Filters* and click *Add*
- Additionally, you may want to add *Unmark Marked Rows* as well

**NOTE: This should be done IN THIS ORDER**

Now, when you navigate back to the second tab, you can click this button / image you have inserted to *remove* the filters applied on the third tab without removing those applied in the first tab.

Another way would be some IronPython... but I'm not going to serve that up since it's even more complicated.

Also, I would look into [Filtering Schemes](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.0/doc/html/filter/filter_filtering_schemes.htm). It doesn't help this question much, since you are creating cascading filters, but I think you'll find it powerful in future analytic designs.

[image: ActionControl]

Comment: Thanks for the answer scsimon. However when I use the button method the filter does not change (if the 'group' filter is changed on tab 3 and I navigate to  tab 2, click the button which has a 'clear all visible filters function', the filter applied on tab 3 does not change. I am using schema's for this at the moment, I should say 'group' schema and 'individual' schema. The python solution seems to be unavailable to me at the minute because of an enterprise decision to lock that out to anyone except a specific few.

Comment: @MartinOLeary are you saying that you are using 3 different filtering schemes? Are you sure you set the button up to clear the filters on tab 3? You could also make it just clear the filters on Tab 2, which would leave you with only the tab 1 filter applied.

Comment: Hey, I don't see where I can select the filters to clear. I put a button in a text area in tab 2, then the function I can attach is "clear all visible filters". But this doesn't clear the filter on tab 3. I must be doing something wrong??

Comment: Yes, you have to add the page which you want to remove the filters from.... in my answer `Available actions > Pages and visualizations: Navigate to the third tab page name and click Add`.  I added an image to what the action control should look like. "Page" is the name of my tab. Here, this should be your third tab name.

Comment: Ah very good, I'll try that tomorrow, could I add another navigate then, navigate back to tab2 maybe?so navigate to tab3, reset filters, navigate to tab2?

Comment: Yup, you sure could. Just depends on what you want.